# Regular expression for "at most"

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am currently thinking about how best to express "At most two" as a regular expression.

`str_detect("xxx", "x{0,2}")` gives `TRUE` and I understand why. For example because of the first two `x`. I want a regular expression that gives `FALSE`. `str_detect("xxx", "x{0,2}[^x]")` achieves this, that's fine. `str_detect("xxx", "x{0,2}(?!x)")` leads to `TRUE`, I am quite surprised because of that. Why is this the case?

Can you think of another regular expressions that are smarter than `x{0,2}[^x]`? I think it's OK but I'm wondering if there is no shorter solution.

Comment: `x{1,2}` will match 1 or 2 `x` anywhere in a string. If you need to find 3 or more, use `x{3,}`. If you want to match a string that only has up to 2 occurrences of `x` anywhere in it, use `^(?:[^x]*x){0,2}[^x]*$` - [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZLVKqQ/1).

Comment: Because in `x{0,2}(?!x)` it can match `xx` when no x is following See https://regex101.com/r/Obb86Z/1 In `x{0,2}[^x]` can not match in a string where there are only x'es

Comment: `x{0,2}[^x]` looks perfectly fine to me, and in fact it captures exactly what you mean

Comment: Great, thank you for your comments! I think `[^x]x{0,2}[^x]` is the best. Because `"xxxa"` matches x{0,2}[^x]. I haven't known the regex tester, it's great!

Comment: If you want to allow no occurrences of x or 1 occurrence which could be directly followed by another x `^[^x]*x{0,2}[^x]*$` https://regex101.com/r/P3tLyv/1

Comment: Ahh now I see the point. When I have a character not only consisting of "x" then the regex `x{0,2}` is enough. `str_detect("exxxe", "ex{0,2}e")` results in `FALSE` of course. I didn't think about it that "xxx" is really a special case and no good example.

Answer (score 2):

You should precise the meaning of "at most". You are using the expression to mean 0, 1 or 2 occurrences, and that is represented with `{0,2}` [limiting quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit).

However, the single char repetition can occur in immediate succession, or within some distance in between. That is, **repetitions may be consecutive and non-consecutive**. In the former cases, we use `x{0,2}` in positive context or `x{3}` in the negative ones, in the latter, we have to use quantified negated character classes that exclude the character, like `(?:[^x]*x){0,2}` (positive context) / `(?:[^x]*x){3}` (negative context).

**What is with the positive/negative contexts?** When you say "at most 2", it is equal to "not more than 3". So, if there are N+1 occurrences of the match, the match should fail. Positive contexts are set with regular consuming contexts in most cases, negative contexts are usually set in negative lookarounds.

**"At most" examples**:

- At most 2 occurrences of *consecutive* `b` characters in a  string: `str_detect(c("aaa","abc","abb","bbb","babnbdb"), "^(?!.*b{3})")` (=> `[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE`)
- At most 2 *consecutive* repetitions of `b` in a word: `str_extract_all("aaa abc abb bbb babnbdb", "\\b(?!\\p{L}*b{3})\\p{L}+\\b")` (=> `[1] "aaa"     "abc"     "abb"     "babnbdb"`)
- At most 2 *non-consecutive* repetitions of `b` in a string: `str_detect(c("aaa","abc","abb","bbb","babnbdb"), "^(?:[^b]*b){0,2}[^b]*$")` (=> `[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE`)
- At most 2 *non-consecutive* repetitions of a `b` letter in any word: `str_extract_all("aaa abc abb bbb babnbdb", "\\b(?!(?:[\\p{L}--[b]]*b){3})\\p{L}+\\b")` (=> `[1] "aaa" "abc" "abb"`)

See the [R demo online](https://rextester.com/UHG16296)

Comment: I would have used the `x` instead of the `b` and using the `\\b` :-) But nice answer++